# Which Quickbooks 7 Enterprise Edition Do I have?

Tags: quickbooks

I am installing Quickbooks 7 Enterprise Solutions onto a Windows 7 machine for one of our employees, as we are upgrading his computer. As I went through the Quickbooks install, near the end, I'm asked to choose an "edition": General Business, Contractor, Manufacturing, Nonprofit, Professional Services, and Retail.

The problem is, I have no idea which edition he's running, and he probably doesn't either, as it's been (probably) several years since Quickbooks was installed on his old computer.

Is there any way that I can find out, by looking in the old computer's registry or Quickbooks Help, which version he has been running?

I would just "pick one" except for the fact that this is a multi-user setup, and others are also using Quickbooks to access the same files. The installation makes it very clear that the same "edition" must be used between all computers accessing the data.

If I did just "pick one", and it turned out to be wrong, would it screw up the data, or is there some sort of safety net built in that wouldn't even allow us to open the data files in the wrong edition?

Comment: Did you contact Intuit support to see which edition had been previously registered/activated with them?

Comment: He's running QuickBooks 7.0? As in QuickBooks from 1997? Intuit only supports the latest 3 or 4 versions (depending on their mood), and will only help you with 2008 (v18.0) to 2011 (v21.0) currently. The license will only allow you to install one version, the product code that accompanies the license number determines that.

Comment: I haven't contacted Intuit precisely for the reason Chris has mentioned. They don't like (or think they need) to do upgrades around here, and that's one of the few software packages we in the IT department can't really manage (weird, long story). All we do is support it. We have 5 user licenses on the software... so Chris, what you're saying is I could select 1 (wrong) edition, and the license wouldn't let me go any further? I just don't want to screw up company data files if I can help it. :D Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Looking at the invoice, it was purchased in 2003. This is Quickbooks Enterprise Solutions. Looks to me like the highest version out right now is 11.

Comment: @David, the "version" out right now is 2011 (v21.0), the year and the version number are different by 10. In any case the license key shouldn't let you install the "wrong" version (it should stop you and tell you that it's an invalid key for the version you're trying to install). Intuit will not support something 8 years old, though they'll happily forward you to the Sales department. QB will not open a file from a version it "doesn't know how to open", so even if you manage to install the wrong version it will not corrupt the file (plus you can just copy the QBW file to make a backup).

Comment: @Chris: Your answer makes sense, and is the one I would have "accepted." A coworker in our IT department and I did some more googling on it, and this is the same answer he came up with. I ended up, yesterday, finishing the installation with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to know which version of QuickBooks you are using,it's very easy to find out.On you keyboard Press F2 key,which will bring product information page.This page contains all information related to QuickBooks application. If you still got confusion you may try to login into your [intuit account](http://camps.intuit.com) using your registered email address.